# Kafka Stopped Working. How to run it again?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Kafka was working just fine for me until about 30min ago. I'm using windows and the commands I use are:

```
c:\kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties
```

to start up zookeeper and then

```
c:\kafka>.\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

to start up the kafka server.

Right now zookeeper isn't working for some reason. That is when I run the command to start zookeeper, nothing happens, a line is skipped in my terminal and I just have:

```
C:\Kafka>.\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties

C:\Kafka>
```

Has this ever happened to anyone? Might someone know how to resolve this?

Comment: If something happened to zookeeper, you are restarting zookeeper, but after that, you have restart the kafka server also

Comment: I have restarted both of them. I closed both of them and then restarted zookeeper and then kafka server. Kafka server seems to run with an error that it can't find the zookeeper client but when I try to run zookeeper nothing runs, using the above prompt.

Comment: Check the contents of the zookeeper log file. The location of the log file would be in the properties. In case you don't understand the contents, add it to the question

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** kafka version which I am using in production **kafka_2.11-2.1.1**

**(2)** OS in which I deployed Kafka

```
        NAME="CentOS Linux"
        VERSION="7 (Core)"
        ID="centos"
```

Required steps to start your kafka Service :-

**Starting zookeeper-server**

- Start your Zookeeper

> [root@ie1 kafka_2.11-2.1.1]# ./bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh
> config/zookeeper.properties

- check port is running or not ( Default port used by zookeeper **:2181** )
- linux commnad to check port is LISTEN or NOT

> ```
> [myhostname@ie1 kafka_2.11-2.1.1]$  netstat -telnup | grep '2181'
> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
>  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> tcp6       0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          1205756192 -
> ```

if you are getting this it mean all are ok, now start follow further steps.

**Starting kafka-server**

- Start your kafka-server

> [root@ie1 kafka_2.11-2.1.1]# ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh
> config/server.properties

- check port is running or not ( Default port used by zookeeper :**9094** )
- linux commnad to check port is LISTEN or NOT

> ```
> [myhostname@ie1 kafka_2.11-2.1.1]$  netstat -telnup | grep '9094'
> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
>  will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
> tcp6       0      0 :::9094                :::*                    LISTEN      0          1205756192 -
> ```

if you are getting this it mean all are ok, now you are ready to go.

Note:- Both services should be run in background otherwise as you will kill you CMD both services would be down.

for Information Please look into log file `

> kafka_2.11-2.1.1/logs/

`

Happy Reading (' ')
Thanks